# Generate TimeStamp In Android Application Project

Tags: android, timestamp

I am working on a project that requires the actions of a user to be time logged and represented as for example : 1 min ago, ...3hrs ago...5 days ago. I am new to this and don't know how to proceed. Keep in mind the project is **NOT** REST based. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Get time in milliseconds for user action, save that time somewhere and then every time take difference of that time with current time to find out how long this action happens

you can get time in millisecond using

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the actual timestamp with:

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Regarding your question you can do something like:

```
long eventTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

..
// some other stuff happens
..

//get the passed time
long actualTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

long timestampDifference = actualTimestamp - eventTimestamp;

int passedSeconds = timestampDifference / 1000; //get the passed time in seconds
int passedMinutes= passedSeconds / 60; //get the passed time in minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are **on Android** you could try the helper class [DateUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long,%20int)) built into Android platform. Something similar to this untested code:

```
String relativeTime = 
  DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
    jud.getTime(), 
    System.currentTimeMillis(),
    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
    DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

If you don't like the API-style or don't find enough features or see other problems like missing timezone awareness then you can also download and try one of two external libraries:

[PrettyTime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) (slim classic library for relative times)

```
// your possible input
Date jud = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600000);

org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime pt = 
    new org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime(Locale.ENGLISH);
String relativeTime = pt.format(jud);
System.out.println(relativeTime); // output: 1 hour ago
```

or my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) (bigger but also more features and languages):

```
// your possible input
Date jud = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600000);

Moment moment = TemporalType.JAVA_UTIL_DATE.translate(jud);
String relativeTime =
    net.time4j.PrettyTime.of(Locale.US)
        .withShortStyle()
        .printRelativeInStdTimezone(moment);
System.out.println(relativeTime); // output: 1 hr. ago
```

Other libraries don't support printing of relative times well, if at all.